# Google Sheet Formula with complex query and multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help to fix a query formula. I am trying to pull specific columns with a criteria. Tried my very best to come up with a formula but I keep on having errors.

Here are the criteria needed for each column:

 data headers = txn headers

 Contact* = full_name

 email* = email but will only shows a unique value

 Product name* = relevant_item_name where it only contains "Not Your Average Membership" or "The Not So Average Membership"

 Billing amt = total where the event is charge

 Status = event either contains charge or rebill based on last order_date

 Last billed* = order_date but only the last date of that email* (especially if it has multiple order dates)

 Cycle = relevant_item_pricing_option when it contains monthly should show "monthly" or One-time payment should show "annual"

 Charges* = the order_id usually shows orderidnumber-chargenumber so only the -x

This is the sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gJn6hHRRKxrvWhRu5WZ-OOXO_EBpMo3_gpFkPlckreQ/edit?usp=sharing

Is it possible to pull in one query? Do I just assume that it's possible but if not can you suggest the best approach on how I can show the required data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gJn6hHRRKxrvWhRu5WZ-OOXO_EBpMo3_gpFkPlckreQ/edit#gid=267885509&range=A16):

```
=SORTN(LAMBDA(z,FILTER(z,REGEXMATCH(INDEX(z,,3),"Average"),REGEXMATCH(INDEX(z,,5),"charge|rebill")))(SORT({txn!D2:D15,txn!S2:S15,txn!AO2:AO15,txn!AB2:AB15,txn!AM2:AM15,txn!X2:X15,IFS(REGEXMATCH(txn!AR2:AR15,"Monthly"),"Monthly",REGEXMATCH(txn!AR2:AR15,"One"),"Annual",TRUE,"N/A"),IFNA(--REGEXEXTRACT(txn!W2:W15&"","-(\d+)"),0)+1},txn!X2:X15,0)),2^99,2,2,1)
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Just a note that the dates in Column X (txn tab) are in mixed formats. Some are in proper date format whilst the others are in text format thats incompatible with formula calculations part. You may want to keep a check on that column in your primary data set by using `ISDATE` function (https://i.imgur.com/nnFc9Mz.png)

Comment: thank you very much. I just did some tweaks to match what I need but your formula really works and match which has been so easy for me to update it. Thank you so much for the help. You're so awesome 

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=SORTN(QUERY(txn!A2:AR, 
 "select D,S,AO,AB,AM,X 
  where AO = 'Not Your Average Membership' 
    and AM matches 'charge|rebill'
  order by X desc", ), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

stuff like `S = UNIQUE(S)` and `X = MAX(X)` are not supported in QUERY

```
|      - or logic
9^9    - return all rows
2      - group by unique mode of sortn
2      - unique for 2nd column outputted by query
1      - in ascending order
```